# how can you change the make of a SFML interface?

Tags: c++, sfml

how can you change the make of a SFML interface?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "The Veterans");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
       sf::Event event;
       while (window.pollEvent(event))
       {
           if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
               window.close();
       }
       window.display();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I want Background to be red. 
Now it's black.

Comment: This is not about *changing* an interface *at all*. It is just about calling the right function to do what you want (`clear()` in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the background of a SFML window, you have to use [`sf::RenderWindow::clear`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a6bb6f0ba348f2b1e2f46114aeaf60f26) with a argument for the color (No argument = Black background). The function call would be:

```
window.clear(sf::Color::Red);
```

This "clears" the window with a red color. Place the call right before the `window.display()`.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you want the window to display something you have to draw it to the screen. Whether that is drawing a shape or an image (or if you are using a RenderWindow, passing a color argument to the clear() method).

Comment: See [this forum](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=8489.0) post for more info on RenderWindow.clear()